# Why isn't my IF statement working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple IF statement, if true, it changes the background color of the div (this).

```js
$(".inner").click(function(){
           
           console.log($(this).css('background-color'));
           
           if($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(255,255,255)'){
              $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
               console.log("IF statement working")
           }/* else {
              $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,255)");  
           }*/
           
       });
```

```css
.outer{
    font-size: 0;
}

.inner{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<div class="outer">
           <div class="inner"></div>
           <div class="inner"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="outer">
           <div class="inner"></div>
           <div class="inner"></div>
       </div>
```

but the second console log does not appear and the color does not change despite the first console log printing the correct color of `rgb('255, 255, 255')`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the value your console printed out... there are spaces, your test value doesn't have spaces

Comment: @PatrickEvans I don't think the output above is a copy/paste, or there wouldn't be quotes around the 3 values, but still needs clarification and worth asking.

Comment: @Archer rgb values will be returned with spaces in them at least with Chrome / Firefox. Test it out in the console on here.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not disputing that at all (and wouldn't rely on it either way).  It most *definitely* would never return `rgb('255, 255, 255')` as posted in the question though (see the single quotes around the values)

Comment: toggle a class, so much easier

Comment: OP is reading the console wrong, that is what the problem is :)

Comment: You have a simple typo:  your console output is `rgb(255, 255, 255)` then you compare that with `rgb(255,255,255)` which is *clearly* not the same *string*.   Adding spaces to your comparison and it works coded.  Voted close as a typo.

Comment: @freedomn-m is right, but even with that fix I wouldn't trust that every browser will necessarily return the exact same string representation for the color "white".

Comment: @DanielBeck agreed - much better to use a class with either .toggle or .hasClass (or .is()) or any other more robust method.

Comment: Yeah: I haven't found a more definitive source, but jQuery docs [say](http://api.jquery.com/css/) "Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's because your IF statement is not true.

`rgb(255,255,255)` does not equal `rgb(255, 255, 255)`

> One has spaces between values, the other does not

Answer (score 0):

As addressed by others that spaces were the root cause. BTW, if you want to swap only background colors then why not just toggle class names instead?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inner').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  font-size: 0;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While relevant, it doesn't answer the question of why the *"if is not working"*

Comment: @freedomn-m, thank you addressing partial explanation.